# Is it possible as a result of the xor, and get an invalid pointer?

Tags: segmentation-fault, null-pointer, xor-linkedlist

I write code for a xor linked list. I have a function where I get a pointer, using the property C.link = A XOR B. Here the code of the this function

```
template <class T>
Node<T>* List<T>::get_next(Node<T>* curr, Node<T>* prev)
{
    assert(curr != 0);
    return (Node<T>*)((int)prev ^ (int)curr->np);
}
```

But in the end get a segmentation fault.Debugging with GDB has shown that the reason for this is the line `return (Node<T>*)((int)prev ^ (int)curr->np);`
in variables such values

```
p *prev
$6 = {data = 2, np = 0x60}
p *curr
$7 = {data = 12, np = 0x804c058}
```

In the end of xor

```
p ((int)prev ^ (int)curr->np)
$8 = 16
```

In my opinion there is not valid pointer, and so it follows segmentation fault. how can I fix it? Thanks

Тhe problem is solved.The problem was in the assignment operator

```
template <class T>
List<T>& List<T>::operator=(const List& l)
{
    if(this == &l)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    delete this->m_head;
    delete this->m_tail;
    this->m_size = l.m_size;
    this->m_head = new Node<T>(l.m_head->data);
    this->m_tail = new Node<T>(l.m_tail->data);
    this->m_head = l.m_head;// problem here
    this->m_tail = l.m_tail;// and here
    return *this;
}
```

I removed these 2 lines and the problem disappeared.

```
int main()
{
    List<int> l;
    l.insertAtBack(5);
    l.insertAtBack(4);
    l.insertAtBack(8);
    l.insertAtBack(9);
    l.insertAtBack(2);
    l.insertAtBack(12);
    List <int> i;
    i = l;
    i.insertAtBack(19);
    l.insertAtBack(21);     
    i.traverse();
    l.traverse();
    if(i == l)
    {
        std::cout << "Objects is equal :)" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Objects is not equal :)" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Main program was called the assignment operator and assigns the head and tail values of the old object to the new object.

Comment: You can stop doing funky math with pointers, for one.  There's a reason you have to force them to ints to XOR them...  :P

Comment: but I did so for example (int)prev. It is not that what you're saying ?

Comment: I'm saying, C++ doesn't really say what XORing two pointers will get you, since it doesn't even allow the operation without you tricking it into thinking they're ints.  You're in IB territory here, at best.

Comment: We should probably see the code that sets `np` in the first place.  Seems to me there's something odd going on there.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `intptr_t` rather than `int`, if you have it...  `int` isn't necessarily big enough to hold a pointer, particularly on 64-bit systems.  In older compilers, `size_t` is more likely to be big enough.
- It looks like `curr` is either pointing at the last element of the list, or at something outside of it.  (`np` being that huge typically means either that it's XORed with a null pointer, or it wasn't set properly.)  Take a look at how you're figuring `np` to set it in the first place; there's something odd there.